# How do I set values in existing Forms and return to original form from a new form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

So I have a form InvCert
I open an instance of form GetSomeInfo
within GetSomeInfo I have textboxes etc and would like those .Text values to become values in the original form InvCert. I assumed Form.stringname = would allow me to do this, but my values are not crossing over to the original form. I have no error messages somehow at the same time.

```
'frmInvCert.certType = comboInvLvl.Text;
frmInvCert.thisYear = dateTimeCurrent.Text;
frmInvCert.myFileName = txtInvestor.Text;
frmInvCert.getAdress = txtAddress.Text;
string certType = comboInvLvl.Text;
new frmInvCert().Show();
this.Close();`
```

Then, these values were made to be used in methods. But the program does not wait until we return to the original form to fill in these values. It just creates blanks.

```
this.Hide();
                new frmGetSomeInfo().Show();
                //creates even if values not filled!
                //May need to retun to original instead somehow or find out how to put these mthods into the new form
                //initialize checkboxes after with paths connected
                //initialize tab pages with paths connected
                if(thisYear != null && certType != null && myFileName != null)
                {
                    CreateCertificate();
                }
                CreateCertificate();
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
new frmInvCert().Show();
```

you are oppening a new instance not the one that you have set the values. change it like this:

```
frmInvCert frm = new frmInvCert();
frm.certType = comboInvLvl.Text;
frm.thisYear = dateTimeCurrent.Text;
frm.myFileName = txtInvestor.Text;
frm.getAdress = txtAddress.Text;
frm.Show();
```

Comment: This still does not seem to work. I am using these values to set a path name for a file.

Comment: public void CreateCertificate()
        {
            //create the certificate within folder\subfolder\thisyear Certificates- 
            certType\certificatehere and overwrites if it exists
            ///Check buffer integer Not sure what that is for
            /////\\BDCSERVER\SDrive\Files\INVESTORS\Investor Certificates\2018 
            Certificates\
            String basePath =

Comment: @"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub\";
            String certificateFolder = $"{thisYear} Certificates- {certType}";
            String correctFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, certificateFolder, $" 
            {myFileName}.ppt");
            File.Create(correctFilePath);
        }

Comment: Instead of the path including these values I get empty values so my folder and sub folder do not have the right names and my ppt file is completely nameless